# Python big space between Button columns

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I want to set my buttons in my Tk window close to each other, but there is too much space between them. They actually have to sit very close to each other, but i can't change their position.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def Page():

    Profile = Tk()

    TreeSearchbar = Text(Profile, width=30, height=1, font="Arial 15")
    TreeSearchbar.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, pady=5, columnspan=2)

    TreeSearchButton = ttk.Button(Profile, text="Search").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W, columnspan=2)


    Tree = ttk.Treeview(Profile, height=20)
    Tree["columns"] = ("value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5", "value6")
    Tree.column("#0", width=170)
    Tree.column("#1", width=180)
    Tree.column("#2", width=0)
    Tree.heading("#0", text="1")
    Tree.heading("#1", text="2")
    Tree.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nw", columnspan=2)

    Button1 = ttk.Button(Profile, text="Delete").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, pady=12, padx=(20, 0))
    Button2 = ttk.Button(Profile, text="Update").grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
    Button3 = ttk.Button(Profile, text="Edit").grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)

    Profile.mainloop()

Page()
```

Comment: _"have to sit very close to each other"_ is very loosely specified I can provide _infinitely_ many answers for the code you've provided achieving that. Please provide a _picture_ of exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using frames inside your grid cells you will be able to pack controls. That will give you more flexibility in the layout, like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def Page():

    Profile = Tk()

    TreeSearchbar = Text(Profile, width=30, height=1, font="Arial 15")
    TreeSearchbar.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, pady=5, columnspan=2)

    TreeSearchButton = ttk.Button(Profile, text="Search").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W, columnspan=2)


    Tree = ttk.Treeview(Profile, height=20)
    Tree["columns"] = ("value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5", "value6")
    Tree.column("#0", width=170)
    Tree.column("#1", width=180)
    Tree.column("#2", width=0)
    Tree.heading("#0", text="1")
    Tree.heading("#1", text="2")
    Tree.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nw", columnspan=2)

    ButtonFrame = ttk.Frame(Profile)

    Button1 = ttk.Button(ButtonFrame,
                         text="Delete").pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
    Button2 = ttk.Button(ButtonFrame,
                         text="Update").pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
    Button3 = ttk.Button(ButtonFrame,
                         text="Edit").pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

    ButtonFrame.grid(row=2, column=0)

    Profile.mainloop()

Page()
```

You should grid your areas in the UI and probably apply this principle in each of them, using either grid again, or packer, inside them (although you can use placer it is usually not recommended, to be able to adjust to window size...)